# Sorting the Dates in the Grid corresponding to the Locale in the Browser

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, date-sorting, columnsorting

[Sorting Image Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDUpJ.jpg)

Greeting,

I am writing a code in dojo that compares the date column in  grid for the sorting. below is the code :

```
function(a,b){
                    var a1=new Date(a);
                    var a2=new Date(b);
                    var x = dojo.date.locale.format(a1, {datePattern: "yyyy-MM-dd", selector: "date"});
                    var y = dojo.date.locale.format(a2, {datePattern: "yyyy-MM-dd", selector: "date"});
                    if((a!=null)&&(b!=null)){
                     if (x.toLowerCase() < y.toLowerCase())
                {
                         debugger;
                         return -1;
                } 
                else if (x.toLowerCase() > y.toLowerCase())
                {
                    debugger;
                         return 1;
                    }
                      else 
                    {
                        debugger;
                          return 0;
                }
                }
```

Code works fine for me when the Language in the browser is English but when I changes to Dutch or any other then it doesnt sorts the values properly.

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're having this problem since those `format` calls ought to be returning the same result regardless, but that code seems severely overcomplicated.

If you are simply trying to sort dates in chronological order, you should merely need to compare them as numbers.

```
var a = [ '2015-10-18', '2015-10-12', '2015-10-16' ];

a.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = new Date(a);
    b = new Date(b);
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});

console.log(a); // ["2015-10-12", "2015-10-16", "2015-10-18"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the above shared code but still its not sorting properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the above shared code but still its not sorting properly.
I have added the Image in the original post. Please have a look and guide.

Comment: Those dates work with the above sort function *if* I pass them in a format that `new Date` can successfully parse.  It cannot, however, successfully parse them directly in the format they're displayed in that image.  What types of values are you actually feeding to this sort function?

Comment: These are some of the values.

var a = ['28-7-2014', '18-12-2014', '27-1-2013','14-12-2014','26-6-2013'];

these values are in Dutch format